# Is there an easy to use XML parser for remote database connection?

Tags: android, xml, database, web-services

I am making an Android app, and I need to connect to a remote database with a webservice.

I will receive an XML file from the webservice with the results of my `SELECT` query (various rows in some cases).

I don't know much about XML or web services, I only know that I will receive an XML file and that I have to parse it to obtain the data.

Is there an XML parser for this purpose that is easy to add to my app and configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designing XML parsers are not very difficult. You can probably google for xml parsers and then change them to look for the tags you need or values.

Google is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not using XML and instead use JSON. JSON is much cleaner and much less in kilobytes. Then I would use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to deserialize the JSON string to an object. You really don't need to do any work. Just point to the URL and you get an object back. You just have to make sure on the webservice you also generate correct JSON, which you can also use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Here is how easy it is:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("user.json"), User.class); // can use File, URL, String!
```

Comment: can you give me a little more info about this?

for example, in the webservice, what i have to do to transform a set of rows (result of a SELECT query) into a JSON object ready to be sent by internet to a android phone?

and also, how can i transform that json object into a set of rows when i have it on my android phone?

code examples will be very good, i am noob on this, and all i am finding on google is very hard for me, can't find anything about set's of rows

Comment: hmm this is a lot of code for me to show somewhere. Let me look around to see what I can find. But right now, take a look at Jackson. You can create all your objects from rows and put them in a list. Then just call a function using ObjectMapper to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an in depth knowledge about XML but you should know a bit about it. A recommended read would be this [article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/10/guide0.html). You should also at least know how the server is handling the communication. Is it a unidirectional communication (your application only fetching data) or is it a bidirectional communication (you are sending requests to the server). If the later how is the server handling them and so on. A bit of background knowledge is required.

I always recommend using the SAX parser as it seems so be the most efficient one due to its concept (being event based). A good read about dealing with XML files on Android can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-android/). And also don't forget to search for similar questions here on StackOverflow as it is quite a popular question with some quality answers.